# Understanding SVN's WebDAV client protocol

Tags: http, svn, webdav

I am trying to use [svnjs](https://github.com/thomfang/svnjs) to implement a client SVN on the web. However, the library is not finished, and doesn't work at all. So I've decided to fix it.

For example, when I add a file and commit it I get a `409 Conflict` error when uploading the new file. I have found [this](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/http-and-webdav/webdav-usage.html) documentation of WebDAV usage in SVN, although it seems unfinished.

> The new file is created within the resulting working collection using a PUT request.

That's all it says. It tells anything about which headers I must include, etc.

So, I have two options/questions:

1. Where can I find more detailed documentation of WebDAV-SVN?
2. There are plenty of SVN clients on Windows/Linux. Is there a tool to inspect outgoing and incoming traffic from that specific app, in order to see working examples?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that you can address your question to the [dev@ Apache Subversion mailing list](https://subversion.apache.org/mailing-lists.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @bahrep 's comment, i found some documentation about how WebDAV/DeltaV works. Here are the links, if anyone is interested:

- WebDAV: http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc4918.html
- DeltaV: http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc3253.html

In my case, I discovered that when receiving a `409 Conflict`, the server had to tell me the reason. From there, I have been able to dig a little more into the errors, and finally solve it.

I haven't pushed the working svnjs yet (it was for another project), but I may at one time push it in https://github.com/royalmo/svnjs . If you come from the future and you're still interested, you may go check that repository.